How to solve "Server Error in '/' Application "

The model backing the 'LawyerDBContect' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.


Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'LawyerDBContect' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Source Error:
Line 16:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 17:         {
Line 18:             var sorgu = db.Kategori.ToList();
Line 19:             return View(sorgu); // Pass the query result to the vie
Line 20: 
Line 18:             var sorgu = db.Kategori.ToList();

I am changing this line var sorgu = db.Kategori it's not listing anything but when I writing var sorgu = db.Kategori.ToList(); this code it's giving me error.
Can anyone help with it.

Have you tried what the error message suggests?..

yes but no effect

Can you explain exactly what you did when following the instructions in the error message.

I am changing this line var sorgu = db.Kategori it's not listing anything but when I writing var sorgu = db.Kategori.ToList(); this code it's giving me error. That's to be expected, db.Kategori is probably a DbSet<Kategori> propert, an IQueryable, so the won't error until it tries to materialize the query as data when you invoke .ToList().
